# Find a word in a crossword

Tags: python, arrays

Write a function named capitalize_word_in_crossword that accepts a 2-dimensional list of characters (like a crossword puzzle) and a string (word) as input arguments. This function searches the rows and columns of the 2d list to find a match for the word. If a match is found, this functions capitalizes the matched characters in 2-dimensional list and returns the list. If no match is found, this function simply returns the original 2-dimensional list with no modification.

Example 1: If the function is called as shown below:

[image]

Text:

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','x','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word)
```

then your function should return:

[image]

Notice that the above list is a representation for a 2-dimensional crossword puzzle as shown below.

[image]

Example 2: if the function is called as shown below:

[image]

Text:

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word)
```

then your function should return:

[image]

Notice that the above list is a representation for a 2-dimensional crossword puzzle as shown below.

[image]

Note: If both a horizontal and a vertical match is found then only select the horizontal match. For example, in the above case there is a horizontal match starting at [2,1] and there is also a vertical match starting at [1,0]. Notice that only the characters in the horizontal match should be capitalized in the returned list.

I have tried this code which only finds the horizontal words.

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word):
    list1=[]
    row_index = -1
    column_index = -1
    refind=''
    for row in crosswords:
        index=''
        for column in row:
            index= index+column
        list1.append(index)

    for find_word in list1:
        if word in find_word:
           row_index = list1.index(find_word)
           refind = find_word
           column_index = find_word.index(word)

    ret = [row_index,column_index]
    if row_index!= -1 and column_index != -1:
        return ret
```

Don't know what to do further. Please help.

Comment: This is a good programming question. But why regex tag ? You don't seem to be using regex here. System will suggest you to use tags based on what is included in your question. For example: your question is related to characters, arrays, strings. But it's your responsibility to decide if you really want to use those techniques or not.

Comment: Because it was in the suggestions and I need answer desperately. @noob

Comment: Can you post the test cases and example code as text? It's hard for me to type the values in manually.

Comment: Displaying code in image files is not helpful because it means everyone will have to type it in themselves if they want to use or edit it for their answer. Beside that, the indentation is wrong in the images.

Comment: Can the words be written diagonally or in a reverse order?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't think so, it ain't mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have posted the test cases below the images in text format. @EvilTak

Comment: Ohh you have also mentioned it in your question as well, sorry for missing it out, corrected my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it is correct.

i had indentation problem and split index for horizontal/vertical

```
def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word):
     i_v=-1
     j_v=-1
     i_h=-1
     j_h=-1
     index_cap = find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word)
     if index_cap is not None:
        i_h,j_h=index_cap
     else:
        index_cap = find_word_vertical(crosswords,word)
        if index_cap is not None:
           i_v,j_v=index_cap


     for row_index in range(len(crosswords)):
         for col_index in range(len(crosswords[row_index])):

             for w in range(len(word)):
                 if i_h is not -1:                       
                    if row_index==i_h and col_index==j_h+w:
                       crosswords[row_index][col_index] = (crosswords[row_index][col_index]).upper()

                 if i_v is not -1:
                    if row_index==i_v+w and col_index==j_v:
                       crosswords[row_index][col_index] = (crosswords[row_index][col_index]).upper()
                    else:
                       crosswords[row_index][col_index] = (crosswords[row_index][col_index])

     return (crosswords)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
crosswords=[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'x', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
words=['cat', 'dog']

def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords, words):
    for rownum, row in enumerate(crosswords):
        for word in words:
            find_index=''.join(row).lower().find(word)
            if find_index>0:
                for i in range(find_index, len(word)+1):
                    crosswords[rownum][i]=crosswords[rownum][i].upper()

    for colindex in range(len(crosswords[0])):
        for word in words:
            colvalues=[row[colindex] for row in crosswords]
            find_index=''.join(colvalues).lower().find(word)
            if find_index>0:
                for i in range(find_index, len(word)+1):
                    crosswords[i][colindex]=crosswords[i][colindex].upper()
    return crosswords

print("Input: "+str(crosswords))
print("Output: "+str(capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords, words)))
```

Output:

```
$ python a.py 
Input: [['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'x', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
Output: [['s', 'D', 'O', 'G'], ['C', 'u', 'C', 'm'], ['A', 'x', 'A', 't'], ['T', 'e', 'T', 'k']]
$
```

`DOG` in 1st row and `CAT` in 2nd and 3rd columns are in uppercase.

The 1st loop just takes everything row by row and finds the index of the word and makes everything uppercase from the found index till length of the word.

The 2nd loop does the same after getting all columns 1 by 1.

Also the above example scales to find multiple words across rows and columns.

Edit 1: just putting everything inside a function

Edit 2: Thanks to Heisenberg. I found something which i missed and fixed it by introducing a temporary step `lower()` function while checking substring because some letters can already be in upper-case(due to previous iterations)

Edit 3: Thanks to Heisenberg again. I missed that point. I just solved it using a normal crossword matching. Here is the corrected version which maintains boolean flags for each word, which is then checked while vertical matching.

```
crosswords=[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
words=['cat', 'dog']
horizontal_match_found=[False, False]
word_index=0

def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords, words):
    for rownum, row in enumerate(crosswords):
        word_index=0
        for word in words:
            find_index=''.join(row).lower().find(word)
            if find_index>0:
                for i in range(find_index, len(word)+1):
                    crosswords[rownum][i]=crosswords[rownum][i].upper()

                if not horizontal_match_found[word_index]:
                    horizontal_match_found[word_index]=True
            word_index+=1

    for colindex in range(len(crosswords[0])):
        word_index=0
        for word in words:
            if not horizontal_match_found[word_index]:
                colvalues=[row[colindex] for row in crosswords]
                find_index=''.join(colvalues).lower().find(word)
                if find_index>0:
                    for i in range(find_index, len(word)+1):
                        crosswords[i][colindex]=crosswords[i][colindex].upper()
            word_index+=1

    return crosswords

print("Input: "+str(crosswords))
print("Output: "+str(capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords, words)))
```

Output:

```
$ python a.py 
Input: [['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
Output: [['s', 'D', 'O', 'G'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'C', 'A', 'T'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
$
```

Note(0 based indexing): since we have a match of `cat` in row 2, we have **NOT** capitalized `cat` in column 0 and in column 2.

Comment: we don't have to capitalize every alphabet of the word everywhere but only when it happens collectively as a word.

Comment: yes the code adhere's to that .. `cat` is present collectively in both 1st and 3rd column

Comment: Output:
[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['C', 'u', 'C', 'm'], ['a', 'C', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
Expected Output:
[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]

Comment: if I give your input to my program: it prints it correctly like this: `Output: [['s', 'D', 'O', 'G'], ['C', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['A', 'C', 'A', 'T'], ['T', 'e', 't', 'k']]`, Note `cat` is present in column 1 and `cat` is also present in row 3 which has been converted to uppercase

Comment: Note: If both a horizontal and a vertical match is found then only select the horizontal match. For example, in the above case there is a horizontal match starting at [2,1] and there is also a vertical match starting at [1,0]. Notice that only the characters in the horizontal match should be capitalized in the returned list.




I think you didn't read this. Your code is capitalizing every word but it should not do that.

Comment: @Heisenberg Oh im so sorry, I had missed that point since I had just coded keeping in mind a normal crossword matching. Corrected my answer, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105504/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-ritesht93).

Comment: can we search the word if it's in diagonal?
[
    ['s', 'D', 'a', 'b'], 
    ['c', 'u', 'O', 'm'], 
    ['a', 'c', 'a', 'G'],
    ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']
]

like here i need to highlight the word 'dog'

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):
    l=[]
    for row in crosswords:
        join_list = "".join(row)
        if join_list.find(word) != -1:
            print([crosswords.index(row), row.index(word[0])])
            return [crosswords.index(row), row.index(word[0])]

def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(crosswords[0])):
            l.append(''.join([row[i] for row in crosswords]))
            for line in l:
                print(line)
                if word in line:
                    row_index=i
                    column_index=line.index(word[0])
                    print([column_index,row_index])
                    return [column_index,row_index]


def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word):
     if find_word_horizontal (crosswords,word) or find_word_vertical(crosswords,word) is not None:
```

I am working here.  Gets `'cat'` and capitalizes it

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','x','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
print(capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word))
```

Comment: isn't the last if line supposed to give error ?

Answer (score 0):

def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):
    l=[]
    for row in crosswords:
        join_list = "".join(row)
        if join_list.find(word) != -1:
            return [crosswords.index(row), row.index(word[0])]

def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(crosswords[0])):
            l.append(''.join([row[i] for row in crosswords]))
            for line in l:
                if word in line:
                    row_index=i
                    column_index=line.index(word[0])
                    return [column_index,row_index]

def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word):

```
 index_cap = find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word)
 if index_cap is not None:
    i,j=index_cap
 else:
    index_cap = find_word_vertical(crosswords,word)
    if index_cap is not None:
       i,j=index_cap


       for row_index in range(len(crosswords)):
           for col_index in range(len(crosswords[row_index])):

               for w in range(len(word)):

                   if row_index==i+w and col_index==j:
                      crosswords[row_index][col_index] = (crosswords[row_index][col_index]).upper()
                   else:                     
                      crosswords[row_index][col_index] = (crosswords[row_index][col_index])

       return crosswords
```

crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','x','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
print(capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word))

It have correct result

=============== RESTART: /Users/valdemarpavesi/Documents/32.py ===============
[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['C', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['A', 'x', 'a', 't'], ['T', 'e', 't', 'k']]

> > > 

but there is a error related to return

## The returned variable type from your function is: NoneType

expected is: list