# Return subsequences of the first list

Tags: python

Create a function called is _subsequence that takes two parameters, both lists of integers, and returns whether or not the second list is a subsequence of the first. For the second list to be a subsequence, every value in it must appear in the first list in the same order. There may be gaps between the values.

I am struggling to return the value based on the order of the first list, here is how i tried:

```
def is_subsequence(list1, list2):
if list1 == list2:
    return True
else:
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list2 in list1:
    return False
```

Comment: How about you provide some sample data that you're working with AND an example of what you want returned?

Comment: hope this post would give you some hint https://stackoverflow.com/q/47893191/1278112

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any sample data AND an example of what you want returned this is the best I could come up with based on the available information. It's python 2 code. If you need python 3 you'll have to adapt it yourself.

```
#!python2

lst1 = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['d', '4'], ['e', '5']]
lst2 = [['b', '2'], ['d', '4'], ['f', '6'], ['h', '8'], ['j', '10']]

# comparing by index 0 and index 1, prints lst1 elements that are in lst2
def is_seq(lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
        if any(i[0] and i[1] in sublst for sublst in lst2):
            print i

print is_seq(lst1, lst2)

'''
['b', '2']
['d', '4']
'''
```